# which kind of design of level shifter suitable for high frequency data transfeing in range of 1MHz?

Tags: digital-logic, voltage-regulator, level-shifting, logic-level

A circuit needed to convert 3.3V and 5V logical voltage. However, the issue was that the circuit was supposed to handle very high data transfer at or above 1 MHz and up to 16MHz.

I thought of

1. using resister(to lower the voltage)
2. use op-amp circuit to rise andowering the circuit.
3. use level shifter. (however they seemed to be working at 400khz, not fast enough)
4. use TXs0108e, but the "Open Drain" wa only at 1.2 MHz.
5. using voltage regulator.
6. Use transistor as gates to operate the circuit. 
   Which design will work for such high speed data transfer?  and which will fall?  how to construct a shifter circuit that handle 16MHz data transfer?

Comment: You could just use a level shifter IC. You do realize there are level shifters that are not open-drain right? Most are push-pull. 1MHz is super slow such a level shifters.

Comment: @DKNguyen but 4 bit bi channel level wasn't faster enough, they work for I2C at 400 kHz, not 10MHz.

Comment: DId you look at the TXB0104?

Comment: @DKNguyen it doesn't have a frequency specification

Comment: Yes it does. Look harder. Also, there are FET level shifters such as the SN74CBTD3384 which aren't push pull or open-drain.

Comment: @DKNguyen I didn't see it, all it talked about was voltage.  i heard about SN74CBDT  but the users were only talking about 1MHz as max not higher.

Comment: Search the datasheet for "Mbps". And who cares what users say? What does the datasheet say? Admittedly it is not so clear from the SN74CBTD3384 datasheet, but it says it has a propagation delay of 0.25ns indicating it should be far in excess of 16MHz

Comment: Are you translating 3.3 V logic to 5 V or vice versa? Or both? Are your individual lines bi-directional or mono-directional?

Comment: @ThePhoton I'm doing both, but 3.3V to 5V has to be at very high frequency and stability.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the isolators section on digi key

https://www.digikey.com/products/en/isolators/digital-isolators/901

or level shifters.

https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/logic-translators-level-shifters/732

Comment: We discourage link-only answers here. As soon as digikey reorganizes their web site your answer has no value.